# How can I attach my branch to my master branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I want to create a new branch attached to my master branch. Just like this:

Master->Dev

In master branch I used

```
git branch dev
git checkout dev
```

In dev, i changed my code now I want to push it so I expect to have something like this:

Master->Dev

However it shows me an error:

fatal: The current branch dev has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin dev

I am trying to learn the git system. So right now I am confused. In the suggestion it says origin dev. But i don't want somethink like this.

Origin->Master

Origin->Dev

I want this:

Origin->Master->Dev

Comment: It doesn't really work like that. Branches are not nested like that or at least it's not displayed like that. You branch from a certain commit, so from the last (head) commit in dev, you can go to its parent. Eventually you will find the commit that was the head of the master branch. Maybe it still is, or maybe not if you committed other changes there. After all, even though they were at the same place at some point, they are still different branches, which can grow in different directions.

Comment: So this is normal, i will run the suggested code and my dev branch's parent will be master's commit right? This is what i want. If it's like this I will run that code now.

Comment: And origin is a remote, a repo.... So `origin->master->Dev` makes no sense.

Comment: Do you know what branches are? And how they relate to commits?